# Organize my constants such as name, class name etc. thorugh an enum

Tags: java, enums

I have few value such as input, output file locations, json fields that I want to retrieve . I have few modules for example, orders, items, etc. The values of input, output file are based on my module. To work with this I have created enums like below.

```
public static enum Modules{
    // 1 : Class name
    // 2 : Output file name
    // 3 : Json field name
    ITEM("Item", "Item", "products.csv", "Item"),
    SALE("Sale", "Sale", "sales.csv", "Sale");

    private final String name;
    private final String className;
    private final String csvFileName;
    private final String jsonFieldName;


    private Modules(final String name,
            final String className, 
            final String csvFileName, 
            final String jsonFieldName) {

        this.name =name;
        this.className = className;
        this.csvFileName = csvFileName;
        this.jsonFieldName = jsonFieldName;
    }
}
```

My question is this: is this the best way in terms of code readability, extensibility, maintainability to organize constants for a module?

Comment: @meskobalazs code readability, extensibility, maintainability when the code grows..

Comment: I dont like organizing constants in interfaces or enumes (generally), however in your case it it more like organizing parameter sets, if they are static using an enum is fine.